# echo id when id is auto increment?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to find this. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question. My first field in my db is an id with INT set to auto increment. When I create a new entry I want to grab the id that was created, but I don't know how.

```
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, "INSERT INTO books (title, author, description) 

VALUES('$title','$author','$description')") 

or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));



echo 'Operation Completed Successfully! <br /><br /><a href="index.php">Click Here</a><br /><br />';


//HERE I WOULD ALSO LIKE TO ECHO THE ID THAT WAS CREATE WITH AUTO INCREMENT
echo $title . "<br />" . $author . "<br /> . $description;
```

Comment: $mysqli->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as mylast;");

Comment: @sskoko there is a specific function available for this (see answers), so no need for a new query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "The last id was: " . msqli_last_insert_id();
```

Comment: you had it right with mysqli_insert_id() http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: I got this:  Fatal error: Call to undefined function msqli_last_insert_id()

Comment: I feel so dumb. I read down through that page  php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php ... before I posted this question, but I am missing something  :(

Comment: If you try `msqli_last_insert_id($myConnection)` ?

Comment: Yes. Even with msqli_last_insert_id($myConnection)  :(  Do I need a null in my last INSERT INTO statement?

Answer (score 3):

Use this function: `mysqli_insert_id()`